# Erro conversão de tipo object para int

Tags: c#, postgresql, cast

Estou fazendo um select no banco de dados, usando o ExecScalar retornando um object porem não consigo fazer um cast deste valor retornado para inteiro.

```
public static int ConsultaPDVsAtivos()
{
    NpgsqlCommand sql = new NpgsqlCommand();
    sql.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(ID) " +
                      "FROM PDV " +
                      "WHERE ATIVO = TRUE;";

    int pdv_count = (int)ConnectionPostgres.ExecScalar(sql); //ERRO
    return pdv_count;
}
```

Método que faz a consulta no banco:

```
//Executa comando com retorno no banco de dados. param: FbCommand
public static object ExecScalar(NpgsqlCommand SqlCommand)
{
    NpgsqlConnection Conn = null;
    try
    {
        // Abre banco de dados 
        Conn = AbreBD();
        SqlCommand.Connection = Conn;
        return SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();

    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Erro ao tentar Criar o Objeto Command: \n ERRO: {0}\n FAVOR ENTRAR EM CONTATO COM NOSSO SUPORTE!", erro.Message));
        Conn.Close();
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        Conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: E você sabe se o retorno de `ExecScalar` tem algo ou é `null`?

Comment: Você não precisa ter `Conn.Close();` no `catch` e no `finally`. O **`finally`** **sempre** vai ser executado, mesmo se a execução cair no catch.

Comment: Tem retorno no ExecScalar e o erro: "Conversão especificada não é válida."

Comment: Você precisa saber qual é o retorno do seu método. Se está estourando este erro que você disse, o retorno não é simplesmente um inteiro "*encaixotado*" num object.

Comment: Parece que ele está retornando um System.Int64

Comment: Por que você acha isso? Se ele tá retornando isso mesmo, você precisa mudar a conversão de `int` pra `long`, isso **se ele for realmente um número muito grande**. Caso contrário, você pode usar `Convert.ToInt32(ConnectionPostgres.ExecScalar(sql));`.

Comment: declarei um object para receber o valor e fiz um GetType() nessa variavel object: System.Int64 e o Convert.ToInt32 funcionou, mas achei estranho nao conseguir fazer um cast explicito.

Comment: É impossível fazer cast explícito de `long` pra `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo comentários, o retorno de `ConnectionPostgres.ExecScalar(sql)` é um `long` *encaixotado* num `object`.

Como `long` aceita números bem maiores que `int`, o *cast* explícito é inviável. Então, você pode tentar fazer uma conversão pra `int`, assim:

```
 int pdv_count = Convert.ToInt32(ConnectionPostgres.ExecScalar(sql));
```

Tome cuidado com isso, porque se o retorno for maior do que o valor máximo de um `int` (`int.MaxValue` - 2147483647) a conversão vai falhar.